# Chaining Concepts in OOP?

Tags: c#, oop

One question I have been asked multiple times in interviews and is related to OOP:

Suppose we have an abstract class `A` with some properties and function.
Then we create a new abstract class `B` that inherits class `A`. Finally, create a class `C` that inherits `B` and is not abstract.

Now I create an object of class `var C = new C();`.
I want that certain properties/functions of class `A` should only be accessible/implemented in class `C` but not in class `B`.
How can I achieve that?

I want to know about this concept.
Here is example code:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract string GetName();
}

public abstract class B : A
{
}

public class C : B
{
}
```

Now I want only class `C` to call `GetName` or implement it. How can I do that?

Comment: use [override](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override) keyword to implement your method.

Comment: To implement `GetName()` in `C` class: `public override string GetName() {...}`

Comment: There is a fundamental difference between *accessible* and *implemented*. Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: That's not possible. A derived class can't change the visibility (public, private, protected, etc.) modifier, and if a member from A can be overriden by C then it can also be overriden by B.

Comment: If you've mixed it up in your question, and they are actually asking how to override a member in B, but not allow it to be overriden in C, then you need to add the `sealed` keyword to the overriden method signature in B.

Comment: You probably are being asked about the [sealed modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sealed) and how to use it in that specific use case.

Comment: In this scenario I think the only way to achieve what you want is to use interfaces. You cannot choose what a derived "intermediate" class can see from parent if this is visible by a child.

Comment: @John its is possible, i want to know how ? because many interviewers asked me this question.I think its a topic from advance OOP

Comment: @OndrejTucny i want to access it in class C ?

Comment: My only conclusion is that you've misunderstood (or misquoted) the question. Your question at the moment asks how you can both access, and implement, a method from _class A_ in _class C_ without being able to do the same in _class B_.

Comment: @John may be say if if only wanted to access the method/property in class C, is there any way i can do that?

Comment: Again, no. If it's accessible in class C, then it's accessible in class B.

Comment: @blfuentes not using interfaces

Comment: @John, Is there any way to allow some properties in Parent class to be only accessible by grandchild not by child?

Comment: @MHanif ok, then the answer is no. You cannot.